# ValueError: shapes (2,2) and (4,6) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, sklearn-pandas

Complaining about this line:

```
log_centers = pca.inverse_transform(centers)
```

Code:

```
# TODO: Apply your clustering algorithm of choice to the reduced data 
clusterer = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(reduced_data)

# TODO: Predict the cluster for each data point
preds = clusterer.predict(reduced_data)

# TODO: Find the cluster centers
centers = clusterer.cluster_centers_

log_centers = pca.inverse_transform(centers)
```

Data:

```
log_data = np.log(data)

good_data = log_data.drop(log_data.index[outliers]).reset_index(drop = True)

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca = pca.fit(good_data)

reduced_data = pca.transform(good_data)

reduced_data = pd.DataFrame(reduced_data, columns = ['Dimension 1', 'Dimension 2'])
```

data is a csv; header looks like:

```
    Fresh   Milk    Grocery Frozen  Detergents_Paper    Delicatessen
0   14755   899 1382    1765    56  749
1   1838    6380    2824    1218    1216    295
2   22096   3575    7041    11422   343 2564
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `pca.inverse_transform()`should not take `clusters`as argument.

Indeed, if you look at the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.inverse_transform), it should take the **data** obtained from the PCA **applied to your original data** and **not** the **centroids** obtained with KMeans.